# Get vehicles coordinates

Tags: sumo

I am using SUMO traffic simulation source code (in windows and Visual Studio) loading the UI and running a scenario.
I need to get all the vehicles coordinates at a certain frequency.
I am looking for a method, in the source code that "moves the vehicles", that I can get the locations?

I know that if I right click in the UI on a vehicle, I can copy it's Geo position of the cursor and set a break point in: GUIGLObjectPopupMenu::onCmdCopyCursorGeoPosition
and get the coordinates, but I am looking for something frequent and constant.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `--fcd-output`, see https://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation/Output/FCDOutput
If you need it online use TraCI or libsumo with the vehicle.getPosition function, see https://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI/Vehicle_Value_Retrieval

Comment: So if I understand correctly. I need to set the --fdc-output "flag", in order to get the data, but I do not need it exported to an xml file, I need, at a certain frequency, to read this data using the C++ source code and add my own code who publishes elsewhere the data. How do I get these location using the source code?